# Using nextProps in setState updater

Tags: reactjs, state

Is there a possibility to use the `nextProps` arg in a `setState` called in `componentWillReceiveProps` ?

From the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) the signature is defined as follows:

```
setState((prevState, props) => stateChange[, callback])
```

so that I don't see how it is possible to use `nextProps` other than using the shallow merge:

```
setState(stateChange[, callback])
```

for instance:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
       data: nextProps.data
    }, myCallBack)
}
```

However this latter is not well suited for multiple `setState` so that I don't want/I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work like you are expecting. Although, since you are reading from props and not state, multiple setState calls shouldn't be an issue.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState( prevState => {
       return { data: nextProps.data }
    }, myCallBack)
}
```

Comment: I found it had to be a pure component

Answer (score 0):

You can update your state in multiple ways:

```
this.setState(() => {
    return {
        data: nextProps.data
    }
});
```

**or**

```
this.setState({
    data: nextProps.data
});
```

It will be the same since you're not updating based on your *state*, but on the *nextProps*. You can also do multiple `setState` calls and **if** they are in the same *render cycle*, React can and will batch these updates for you.